# How to "glue" two "boxes"?

Tags: page-breaking, columnbreak, glue

I have a command `\sectionExercise{...}` that produce a title followed by a thick horizontal line.

This command is always followed by a minipage : `\begin{exo}...\end{exo}`

Sometimes, there is a column break between the title (of a series of exercises) and the exercises.

**In general, is there a way to prevent a column or page break between two "boxes"?**

## Example of such a column break

[image]

## Some code

```
\newcommand{\sectionExercise}[1]{%
\vspace{8mm plus 2mm minus 1mm}
%\bigskip
{\bfseries \Large #1\par}
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum width=\columnwidth, minimum height=2mm] (a) {};
    \draw[color=blue!30, fill=blue!30, rounded corners=2pt] (a.south west) -- (a.north west) -- (a.north east) -- (a.south east) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\gdef\varIsNewSectionExercise{1}
}
```

Comment: You can add, say, `\penalty-\@lowpenalty` before the `\sectionExercise` and `\nobreak` between the horizontal rule and the first exercise. This *may* work. For a more concrete answer *please* post a working example. You've been around here longer than me, you should know that by now...

Comment: Yes I know, of course!

Comment: @Colas If the solution posted by me _works as a charm_, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\needspace{...}` from `needspace` package inside of your `\sectionExercise` command.

**Edit:** Someone pointed out in the comments that my answer is short, without references nor example... and is right. The fact is that I don't have a MWE to work with. Regarding references, the package comes with the official distribution of TeX Live and has a [short documentation of only two commands](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/needspace/needspace.pdf). The actual solution is just to use the command with almost any lenght (in this case), i.e. using `\needspace{4\baselineskip}` at the beginning of the definition of the command defined by OP. All other thing could remain unchanged and doesn't have particular conficts with other packages (**maybe** it could not behave as expected if `\flushbottom` is in effect).

**Edit:** Just for future readers. This problem arise also with default commands like `\section` and similar. By default LaTeX considers ugly putting the title of a section at the end of the page and the text at the beginning of the new page. However, if `\section` is followed by `\subsection` it can happen. I don't know why it don't handle automatically this situation, probably because one shouldn't put a new subsection right after section. However, in this cases, instead of using `needspace` one could use the right options given by `titlesec`.

Comment: Please expand your answer so that it is self-contained (e.g. that the parameter of needspace is a length and maybe a real code example).

Comment: @TeXnician How I'm supposed to do that if OP doesn't even posted a mwe that I should adjust? Beside, almost every lenght is ok, but if I add a particular lenght maybe some future reader may thinks that it's a particular lenght.

Comment: You could leave `\needspace{...}` and add:  `for example \needspace{2\baselineskip}`.

Comment: Hope that this is enough. Otherwise please point out what I should add.

Comment: Your answer is good, suggest you delete the `*` and amend to `\needspace{4\baselineskip}`. By the way, I upvoted your answer. Yes, lack of minimal working example made your answer more difficult to be comprehensive. The documentation of `needspace` package is very brief. I didn't know about this package until I read your answer.

Comment: I discovered this package on this site a while ago to solve problems similar to the one of OP.